# Do we have to use free variables in Hilbert systems?

Tags: predicate-logic, proof-theory, hilbert-calculus

I find it very unpleasant using free variables in proofs, because it puts lines in proofs which have no intuitive meaning. This is clearly necessary for natural deduction, but I was wondering if it was necessary for the (standard) Hilbert system. Clearly, we could just modify any system so that all inference rules work inside quantifiers, i.e. if we have quantifier $Q$ and inference rule $A,B,C...\vdash Z$, then we add $Qx A,Qx B,Qx C...\vdash Qx Z$, but I was wondering if this was necessary. We just need to do this with the universal quantifier, and we can do this with modus ponens: if we start off with a universally quantified formula $A$ and the universally quantified formula $A\rightarrow B$, we can distribute the quantifiers over the second to obtain $B$ with a universal quantifier. But can we do this for modus ponens with multiple quantifiers, and can we obtain the axioms of the Hilbert system with arbitrarily many multiple quantifiers within the Hilbert system, while avoiding using free variables? I'm sure the answer is no, but it would be nice to have it confirmed.

Comment: It's possible to completely avoid free variables in certain Hilbert-style deduction systems. My answer [to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3963550/is-it-possible-to-hide-auxiliary-statements-introduced-by-universal-and-existe/3963633#3963633) contains a reference to a book which tells you how to construct such a system.

Comment: On a somewhat related note: "lines with free variables have no intuitive meaning" seems to have become a recurring [trope](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962218/is-there-a-proof-system-for-first-order-logic-that-does-not-use-premisses-and-au) at this point, and I'm trying to trace its origins. Did you have this thought independently, or do you remember reading it somewhere?

Comment: @Z.A.K. Independently while doing natural deduction proofs a few years ago. I find my aversion very natural, but of course I would. It's like saying vings are blims, and blims are nergs, therefore vings are nergs. Sure it gets you where you want to go once you introduce quantifiers, but you shouldn't be able to assign truth values to statements about vings or blims when you haven't clarified what they are, and lines in proofs should be true.

Comment: You aversion is totally unmotivated; you assign meaning to symbols through an interpretation. An interpretation is a sort of "context": there are simple formale mechanisms to - given a context - assign a "temporary" meaning to free variables also. Mathematics is full of free variables: $(x^2-1)=(x-1)(x+1)$

Comment: My preference is purely aesthetic. You can assign meaning to symbols through a model. But in practice you don't, e.g. when you use universal generalisation, you're just thinking about a name as representing some unspecified thing, and you can introduce a quantifier by virtue of the fact that it is unspecified. Now, if you start off with a free variable, then you think of that as having exogenous meaning. That's different. Also, your example would be implicitly quantified in any realistic setting.